# Show that the function is differentiable at (0,0)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
(x^2+y^2)\sin(y/x),  & \text{if $x\neq 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ =0}
\end{cases}$$

MY ATTEMPT:
I tried to solve this question using the definition of differentiability for the functions of two variables.
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{(f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)-hf_x(a,b)-kf_y(a,b))}{{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}}
\end{equation}
which should come equals to 0 for the function to be differentiable.
First I tried to find out $f_x$ which comes out to be 0.
\begin{equation}
f_x=
\lim_{(h)\to (0)}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f_y=
\lim_{(k)\to (0)}\frac{f(0,k)-f(0,0)}{k}=\text{undefined}
\end{equation}

so please help me out with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all we know that $$ |\sin(y/x) |\leq 1$$ for all $x,y$. And, if $x = 0$ then the function is $0$.

Thus, we can just do a trivial bound to get that
$$ \frac{1}{|(x,y)|} | f(x,y) - f(0,0) | \leq \frac{1}{|(x,y)|}|x^2 + y^2| = |(x,y)| \to 0$$ and so $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and the derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f_x = 0, f(0,y) = 0 \implies f_y = 0$. Thus you only need to show: $\displaystyle \lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{f(h,k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = \displaystyle \lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \sqrt{h^2+k^2}\sin(\frac{k}{h}) = 0$. But this is true by squeeze theorem since $\left|\sin(\frac{k}{h})\right| \le 1$.